# Torrent box, but dumped to hard drive on PC, possible?

Tags: pi-3

I'm a to-be first time Pi user here with amateur-level linux experience.

I hope to set up a rPi such that it torrents to the microSD card (64GB), but set it so that in the day time it'll wirelessly transfer the bits downloaded to my main HDD in my PC via local Wi-Fi. Of course, a torrent may not be completely downloaded within 1 night, but I don't want it to start from the beginning again the next night, but from where it reached the previous night, even though the data files are gone.

Is such a set up possible? Are there torrent/sync managers that have this feature?

Comment: Why not just mount a CIFS share (Assuming your main PC runs Windows)  and use that as your torrent download destination?

Comment: @Lawrence thank you for the reply, I'm looking into CIFS/SMB setup gudes now. Just to confirm, it enables rPi and main windows PC to simultaneously read/write to a hard drive on the main PC, right? Much like Windows' Homegroup?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Similar to Homegroup. SMB/CIFS is the protocol that Homegroup uses to share files between Windows computers.

Comment: @Lawrence thank you for clarifying! I'm diving in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Setting up a Raspberry Pi as a NAS would be much easier, but..

You could install Deluged and set it to move completed downloads the set `crontab -e` that runs a bash script to check the folder for files then uses scp (secure copy) and send it to a **ftp server** running on your windows box

## Install Deluge

```
sudo apt-get install deluged && sudo apt-get install deluge-console && sudo apt-get install python-mako && sudo apt-get install deluge-web deluge-web

#then reboot
sudo reboot


#run the deluge console
deluge-console
    config -s allow_remote True 
    config allow_remote exit
    #exit the console


#then back in the terminal to start the webpage
deluge-web
```

Then browse to https://localhost:8112 The default password is **deluge**

Then click preferences -> Downloads -> Tick Move Completed to -> MyFolder

Comment: thank you for the reply and concise guide, I think this will be a solid fall-back option, since my downloads usually take many nights to complete (slow Australian internet).

Comment: @Fire If this answer help you so please accept it with a click on the tick on its left side. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.